# Display Customer address in different lines

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf

we got below test order with below shipping address :

[image]

when i download it in **pdf** from sales order grid, i got as below image:

[image]

but i need to display the address in many lines as like 1st image.....

my code :

```
public function generatePdfAction()
    {     
        $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_number');
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
        $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();

        $pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
        $page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
        $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES);
        $page->setFont($font, 12);
        $width = $page->getWidth();
        $i=0;

        $page->drawText('Order Id# '.$order->getIncrementId(), 20, $page->getHeight()-20);
        $page->drawText($shippingAddress->getFormated(true), 20, $page->getHeight()-40);
        $pdf->pages[] = $page;



        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('info'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').
                '.pdf', $pdf->render(), 'application/pdf');

        //$this->_redirectReferer();
    }
```

Also i replaced below code :

```
$page->drawText('Order Id# '.$order->getIncrementId(), 20, $page->getHeight()-20);
        $page->drawText($shippingAddress->getFormated(true), 20, $page->getHeight()-40);
        $pdf->pages[] = $page;
```

by this code  :

```
$page->drawText('Order Id# '.$order->getIncrementId(), 20, $page->getHeight()-20);
        $page->drawText("TO", 20, $page->getHeight()-40);
        $page->drawText($shippingAddress->getStreet(). " ". $shippingAddress->getRegion(), 20, $page->getHeight()-60);
        $page->drawText($shippingAddress->getCountry(), 20, $page->getHeight()-80);
        $page->drawText($shippingAddress->getRegionCode(), 20, $page->getHeight()-100);
```

Now when i open pdf, its displayed like below image :

[image]

Comment: Use \n in the place of <br>

Comment: @MohamedElMrabet thanks i found solution using below answer.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, You have to print text in new line just like below

```
$shippingAddr = $shippingAddress->getFormated(true);
$breaks = array("<br />","<br>","<br/>");  
$textChunk = str_ireplace($breaks, "\r\n", $shippingAddr);  
$innerCnt = 0;
foreach(explode("\n", $textChunk) as $textLine){
    if(strip_tags(ltrim($textLine))!=""){
        $addInnerHeight = $innerCnt * 14;
        $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($textLine)), 20, ($page->getHeight()-(40+$addInnerHeight)), 'UTF-8');
        $innerCnt ++;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks, got same error as `There was an error opening this document`, please check code : https://pastebin.com/bVf2WSec

Comment: un comment `$pdf->render();` this code

Comment: uncommented, sorry still the same issue.....

Comment: add this code before preparedownload line  `header('Content-type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="exportPO.pdf"');

        echo $pdf->render();`

Comment: updated as per your suggestion, no luck , here is updated code : https://pastebin.com/zxAdELpz

Comment: `echo $pdf->render();` should come after header

Comment: thanks a ton, you made it this time, can you please help me to remove the extra spaces which present in between each lines, now its displaying like : https://prnt.sc/hftp5o , i need like http://prntscr.com/hftpk6

Comment: I think in this code `str_ireplace($breaks, "\r\n", $shippingAddr); ` remove \r and try

Comment: sorry, that didt helped to remove spaces.....

Comment: Can you give me previous text with <br> so I can check

Comment: thanks, please check : https://pastebin.com/UFxsAXeW ,  i used part1 code [my code ]  & part 2 code [ your code ] ,  now both results are merging as image : http://prntscr.com/hftv02 , but i need part 2 results should display below part 1 code.....

Comment: Check your Height and calculate yourself `$page->getHeight()-60`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69330/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-murtuza-zabuawala).